# Is it possible to check if some type doesn't exist in a parameter pack

Tags: c++11, c++14, variadic-functions, template-meta-programming

I'm working on a C++14 project and I just wrote a function with parameter pack.

```
template <typename... Args>
void func(Args&&... args) {
    ...
}
```

The `args` should contain only `int` or `std::string`, it can't be any other types.

Is there any way to do the check at compile time? Maybe something as below?

```
template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<???* = nullptr>
void func(Args&&... args) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to disable the function template or is it sufficient that there is a compile error when the function is used with wrong types? The latter can be achieved with a suitable `static_assert` declaration in the body.

Comment: Your tags and your question text disagree about the C++ version. Please make up your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets better with folds in C++17 and concepts in C++20, but you can test each element against `int` and `std::string`.

The first end of the recursion is the primary template. If no specialisation matches, we are false.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string : std::false_type {};
```

The other end of recursion is the empty pack, which is true.

```
template <>
all_int_or_string<> : std::true_type {};
```

If we find `int` or `std::string` as the first element, recurse the remaining elements

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<int, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<Ts...> {}

template <typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<std::string, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<Ts...> {}
```

You probably also want to strip off qualifiers.

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<const T, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<T, Ts...> {}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<volatile T, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<T, Ts...> {}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<T &, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<T, Ts...> {}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_int_or_string<T &&, Ts...> : all_int_or_string<T, Ts...> {}
```

Used thusly

```
template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<all_int_or_string<Args...>::value>* = nullptr>
void func(Args&&... args) {
}
```